# Bootstrap 3 - how to create responsive fixed right menu, with scroll

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

In the next image you can see what I want to achieve:

Desktop
[image: Desktop version]

Mobile

[image: Mobile Version]

How can I do this?

I've been trying something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10" style="overflow:auto;">
        <h1>Profile</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer id ligula tincidunt eros eleifend porttitor. Maecenas cursus volutpat erat.
        </p>
      </div>

      <!--feeds-->
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h3>-- Feeds --</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!--fixed menu-->
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:#2ecc71;padding:3px;">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img src="/img/1.png" class="img-circle" style="max-width:150px">
      <h3>hi!</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- menu links -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @vanburen done it!

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to place a menu on the left or the right because the image shows it on the right but says _fixed left menu_.

Comment: @vanburen Sorry mate! I want it on the right side, my mistake (edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do. You could use the default Bootstrap `navbar` by changing it's position rules (`position: fixed;`) to suit your needs while inside of a media query so once you're below 768px your nav adjusts to the default toggle nav. See [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) for reference.

**Working Example**: Open at full page and reduce the viewport.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.sidebar-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: #222;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .navbar.sidebar-nav .navbar-header {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.sidebar-nav .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    float: right;
  }
  .navbar.sidebar-nav .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .navbar.sidebar-nav .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .main-content {
    margin-right: 200px;
  }
}
/*THUMBNAIL FOR DEMO ONLY*/
.thumbnail {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  padding: 25px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 12.5px auto;
}
/*THUMBNAIL FOR DEMO ONLY*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top sidebar-nav">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button data-toggle="collapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#bs-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Two</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Three</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Four</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/000/000" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450/f00/f00" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: simply AWESOME!! Thanks so much!

Comment: sorry for bothering you again. Imagine that links in navbar have icons. Can the navbar collapse, so only icons get visible?

Comment: How are you trying to implement this thought? You as the viewport changes size the icons are left and the text would be hidden or you mean to toggle the navbar to a reduced size?